# Authorization token generation for Azure Resource Management Rest API

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, active-directory

I am going to call Azure Resource Management Rest API from my Spring Boot application. For that i need to have authorization token. After googling thorough different sources, i could understand that we need to call POST API to generate Authorization token using below URL;

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token

with below request body, Below details i have got by creating service principle and Active directory

client_secret
resource
grant_type
tenant_id

Spring boot java code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    String url= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token";
    AuthTokenBody authTokenBody = service.setBody();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    HttpEntity<AuthTokenBody> entity = new HttpEntity<>(authTokenBody, headers);
    ResponseEntity response= restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, ResponseEntity.class);
```

But i get below error:

{
    "timestamp": "2018-12-23T11:52:58.175+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "400 Bad Request",
    "path": "/cdaas/app"
}

Can you please guide how to call generate Authentication code in Spring-boot to cal Azure Resource management.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe this could help you.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/23/authenticating-azure-resource-management-rest-api-requests-using-java/

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below code, it works for me.

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential; // for service principal

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class GetAuthCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Account specific values
        String tenantId = "***";
        String clientId = "***";
        String password = "***";

        // use adal to Authenticate
        AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;

        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/authorize";
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(url,
                    false,
                    service);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, password);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireToken(
                    "https://management.azure.com/",
                    clientCred,
                    null);
            authResult = future.get();
            System.out.println(authResult.getAccessToken());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle exception as needed
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

More details,please navigate to this [doc](http://innerdot.com/azure/authenticating-to-azure-resource-manager-using-java).

Comment: What about refresh-token?

Comment: why authResult.getRefreshToken() is null?